# Android Button: multiple shapes and icon + text

Tags: android, xml, android-button

I'm trying really hard to create the following button but having no luck so far:

http://3d-sign.com/ss.jpg

I would like the left (red) and right (dark gray) parts of the background to be done with shapes so I can change the colors however I see fit. So essentially the background of the button would be formed of 2 different shapes, one smaller one that's the bg for the icon and one larger one that's the bg for the text. The icon on top of the red portion of the background will always be white and a PNG image and the text to the right would be part of the button. I tried a bunch of different ways with drawableLeft and layer lists but really just can't see it through.

Can anyone please help? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a [9-patch drawable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch), it's much simpler.

You need to create a png image, with an extra pixel row/column on each side, where black pixels indicate the *scalable areas* and the *fill area* (i.e. where the text goes). So you can basically take this image you provided, add this metadata, and you're good to go.

Plus, the rounded corners won't be stretched out of shape if the button needs to grow either horizontally or vertically.

See: [A simple guide to nine patch](http://radleymarx.com/blog/simple-guide-to-9-patch/) for a good, comprehensive explanation.